# Comparing arrays with index

Tags: python, arrays

I need a way to compare multiple arrays of number in a *fastest* possible way. For instance, I have

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[2, 2, 3, 1]
[2, 2, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 3]
```

The sorting goes as follows: The most significant element is at index 0, so all arrays with value 1 at index 0 are before those with value 2 at index 0. If index 0 is the same then index 1 is used to compare two arrays.

```
sorted_arrays = sorted(arrays, key: lambda x: x)
```

does what I want to do, but it's rather slow. I think it's pairwise comparing all elements and isn't much faster than another naive implementation I came up with:

```
class Array(object):
    def __init__(self, values):
        self.values = values

    def __cmp__(self, other):
        for arr1, arr2 in itertools.izip(self.values, other.values):
            if arr1 < arr2:
                return -1
            elif arr1 > arr2:
                return 1
        return 0

arrays = sorted([
   Array([1, 2, 3, 4]),
   Array([2, 2, 3, 1]),
   Array([2, 2, 2, 3]),
   Array([1, 2, 3, 3])
])
```

Is there perhaps a faster way to do this (without comparing each array with each other array (and possibly all elements of the array))?

Comment: "... but it's rather slow." Have you tried not specifying a `key` argument? Have you tried sorting in-place?

Comment: No, I haven't. Is that how `sorted()` would sort arrays by default? No, I haven't tried in-place either.

Comment: Python's sort routines already use the element as the key. All adding an identity `key` argument does is slow down execution since the function will be called for every element.

Comment: Think about it: `lambda x: x` is a function which accepts `x` and then returns it right back. Why send it to the function in the first place? It doesn't change anything.

Comment: Well, I didn't know that's what `sorted()` was doing internally. It might as well have used the identity of the list...

Comment: Did you check the documentation?

Comment: No, I assumed it worked the way I thought it would... Did you?

Comment: I refer to the tutorial and documentation frequently.

Comment: @orange .. Should check this: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sorting.html?highlight=sorted#sorting-how-to and https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=sorted#sorted